# parallel request using multiprocessing.dummy

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing

I trying run parellel get requests using multiprocessing.dummy with report by progress.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from functools import partial
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
        self.threads = 10
    def callback(self, total, x):
        self.count += 1
        if self.count%100==0:
            print("Working ({}/{}) cases processed.".format(self.count, total))
    def do_async(self):
        thread_pool = Pool(self.threads)#self.threads
        input_list = link
        callback = partial(self.callback, len(link))
        tasks = [thread_pool.apply_async(get_data, (x,), callback=callback) for x in input_list]
        return (task.get() for task in tasks)
start = time.time()
t = Test()
results = t.do_async()
end = time.time()`
```

the result of the operation - the same time as the non-parallel requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution in  concurrent.futures:

```
import concurrent.futures as futures
import datetime
import sys
results=[]
print("start", datetime.datetime.now().isoformat())
start =time.time()
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
    fs = [executor.submit(get_data, url) for url in link]
    for i, f in enumerate(futures.as_completed(fs)):
        results.append(f.result())
        if i%100==0:
            sys.stdout.write("line nr: {} / {} \r".format(i, len(link)))
```

Answer (score 2):

CPython is inherently single-threaded due to something called the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). This means only one thread can run at a time, even if there are multiple CPU cores available. `multiprocessing.dummy` is just a wrapper for using threads, so this is why you are not getting a speed up.

To get the benefit of having multiple CPUs, you must use `multiprocessing` itself. However, there are overheads based on the cost of sending and receiving the input and output data of the sub-process. If the cost of this is greater than the amount of work done by the sub-process then using `multiprocessing` can actually slow your program down. So in your example, `multiprocessing` would likely not give you a speed increase. This is especially true as most of the work in the callback involves printing to standard out, which all the processes in the pool must synchronise over to prevent garbage being printed out.